# UK marriage visitor visa

Tags: united-kingdom, uae

I’m in UAE Dubai, and my fiancée in the UK wants to live with me in the UK. When we apply for a spouse visa, there are requirements that are difficult for us (financial). The threshold is £18,600. She is a nursery nurse, and her annual salary is £14,000.

My question is, if we go for a marriage visitor visa, would we be able to change to a spouse visa or ILR?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't meet the threshold income you [probably] won't get a spouse visa.

Edit: as mentioned in comments, there are certain exceptions to the income requirement. They include if the person in the UK is disabled or is a carer (but that does not mean a professional carer like your fiancée). Another is if you already have a child living in the UK.

Edit: I misread the job title and the below does not apply.

However, your fiancée is a nurse. The base salary for a full time nurse in the NHS is around £22,000 so maybe she should change jobs as her present one seems to be underpaid.

Comment: The OP's original post said "nursery nurse." As best I can tell, in British English that means a childcare worker rather than a healthcare one, which would be a different payscale.

Comment: Nursery nurses in the UK are often employed in the private sector where the National Living Wage of £7.83ph would apply but there’s no common payscale as such. A Nursery Manager in the private sector would likely earn around £25kpa

Comment: There is the 10 year route in special circumstances if you don't meet the financial requirements. you should probably add that to the answer.

Comment: @zachlipton I edited to take account of your correction

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is whether the couple could use a marriage visitor visa.

Comment: @phoog literally true, so I upvoted your answer. But the asker's objective is to live in the UK on a spouse visa and I did address that (eventually). There is a recurrent issue of people asking questions that betray a fundamental misunderstanding of their own predicaments.

Answer (score 1):

> if we go for a marriage visitor visa, would we be able to change to a spouse visa or ILR?

No.  A marriage visitor visa is for people who want to marry in the UK without moving there.  That's why its name includes the word *visitor.*  See the government's [overview page](https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa), which shows that one of the requirements is:

> you’re not planning to stay or settle in the UK after your marriage or civil partnership